# Display value in column Array VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Could someone explain my why my code display values at columns instead of rows ? Thanks

```
Function ShiftVector(rng As Range, n As Integer)

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim B As Variant
Dim A() As Variant
Dim nr As Integer
nr = rng.Rows.Count
ReDim B(nr)
ReDim A(nr)

For i = 1 To nr - n
    B(i) = rng(i + n)
Next i
For i = nr - n + 1 To nr
    B(i) = rng(i - nr + n)
Next i

ShiftVector = B
End Function
```

Comment: Firstly, what is `n`? Then, you load a 1D array, which by definition does not have rows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code loads a 1D array, which does not have rows by definition... Then, you do not explain what `n` means and I will make abstraction of its 'contribution' in the function... The next interpretation assumes that `rng` is a **range containing only a column**.

There are two ways of solving it:

1. Let the code as it is, but finally use:

```
ShiftVector = Application.Transpose(B)
```

2. ReDim and load a 2D array:

```
  ReDim B(1 to nr, 1 to 1)
  'and load it in the next way:
   B(i, 1) = rng(i + n)
```

3. You can place a range directly in a (2D) array:

```
  B = rng.value
```

If you will explain what `n` wants to be, I can adapt the answer to somehow take it in consideration...

**Edited**:

Please, play with the next function, able to make slices from a 2D array and 'mount' them in a different order:

```
Function ShiftVector2D(rng As Range, n As Integer) As Variant
 Dim nr As Long, arr, arrSl1, arrSl2

 nr = rng.rows.count - rng.row + 1 'the number of the range rows, even if it does not start from the first row...
 arr = rng.Value                                 'place the range in a 2D array
 With Application
        arrSl1 = .Index(arr, Evaluate("row(1:" & n & ")"), 1)                         'obtain an array slice of the first n rows
        arrSl2 = .Index(arr, Evaluate("row(" & n + 1 & ":" & nr & ")"), 1)    'obtain an array slice of the rows after n up to the last row
        arr = Split(Join(.Transpose(arrSl2), "|") & "|" & Join(.Transpose(arrSl1), "|"), "|") 'created a 1 D array by joinning the two arrays and split them by "|"
        ShiftVector2D = .Transpose(arr)   'return the 2D necessary shifted array
 End With
End Function
```

You can test it placing some strings in the range "A1:A10" and run the next code:

```
Sub testShiftVector2D()
  Dim rng As Range, arr
  Set rng = Range("A1:A10")

   arr = ShiftVector2D(rng, 4)
   Debug.Print Join(Application.Transpose(arr), "|")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I redim-ed loaded the values in a 2D array. n - value is the number of rows I wanted to shift my elements up.

Comment: @Patryk Zborowski Too busy/lazy to try understanding it... Having 5 minutes now, I will play with arrays to make an equivalent function not needing iteration... :)